# The silver-haired female main character is a princess and has power to see future through water

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember that the female lead is a princess with silver hair and she's mistreated by her father who dotes on her younger sister. She gets married of to an enemy country in place of her sister. She has the power to see the future through water. The male lead is brown haired with a tan.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this an anime or a manga/manhwa/manhua?  When and where did you see/read this?

Comment: Please post an answer to your question instead of editing.

Answer (score 4):

This is "[Forget My Husband, I’ll Go Make Money](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/forget-my-husband-ill-go-make-money/)."  Quoting from the summary at the above link:

> Aristine, a princess confined out of the Emperor's sight.
>
> When in reality, she was the owner of the [Monarch's Sight], able to see the future, past, and present.
>
> She, who became the sacrifice for a political marriage, was married off to a terrifying barbarian…
>
> "The most precious things should naturally be given to my bride."
>
> But her husband, whose monstrosity she prepared for, was way too normal.
>
> However, he belonged to someone else.
>
> "I'll go make money then."
>
> She might as well make the goldfields her own.

Princess Aristine, first daughter of the Emperor, was discarded by her father when she was 6 for failing to manifest the clairvoyant power of the Imperial bloodline.  Her secret, however, is that Royal Sight *did* come to her, but as a young child she was traumatized enough that she couldn't speak of it.  Aristine has white hair and purple eyes.

She spent 10 years closely confined, with nothing to do except to watch her visions and learn from them, until the Emperor decreed that she should be sent (instead of her favoured, acknowledged, younger sister) as a political pawn in an arranged marriage with a prince of the Irugo people.  The Irugo had recently successfully fought off an attack by the Empire, and the ostensible purpose of the marriage was to seal a peace.  The Emperor, however, intended for Aristine to be killed and for that to be justification to renew the war.

Aristine, however, has foreseen all this, and intends to take advantage of being away from the Empire to establish herself independently and take power back from the courtiers who have bullied and belittled her.  She doesn't care that Tarkan, the Irugo prince she is betrothed to, has a lover; she doesn't love Tarkan and only desires a political partnership to further both their goals.

Aristine's visions, which she can't really control, manifest in any liquid she is staring at; a puddle, a bath, a cup of tea, etc.

[image: An image of a woman talking appearing in a cup of tea, pulling out to see the people she's talking with, then clearing to show Aristine's reflection in the teacup.]

Other confirming details from the introductory chapter:

[image: The Emperor, eyes shadowed, looks down from his throne "Prepare to leave for Irugo." Aristine, face dirty, in a dirty smock, stares back. Courtiers murmur in the background "A political marriage with those barbarians!?" "She's still a princess..." Aristine's blonde-haired, green-eyed younger sister is shown as more murmurings are recorded: "They both share the blood of the Emperor, yet he only cares about one of them." Caption: "Aristine, Princess of Silvanus" The Emperor speaks, "Be grateful my daughter." Caption: "Ordered by her father, the Emperor, into a political marriage with the hostile country of Irugo." Aristine's face again, Emperor off-screen: "For how useless you are, you can at least serve some purpose thanks to the noble blood that runs through your veins."]

[image: Princess Aristine, depicted in regalia with an orb-headed sceptre; midway through the frame a darkening division reveals chains around the princess. Narration reads: "Princess Aristine. Although she was of royal blood, she was believed to never be able to inherit the [Royal Sight], and thus ended up living her whole life locked up." Against a background of a chain shattering, the narration reads: "But thanks to a marriage intended to end a war, she was finally brought into the outside world. Under normal circumstances, becoming the symbol of peace would have been the start to a happy and virtuous life! ...But!" A red-haired lady-in-waiting wearing a green dress berates the princess: "-Have you forgotten what His Majesty said?! You must never forget your duty, Princess!" "...My duty?" "Don't you remember? Your duty is to die for our country!"]

[image: Princess Aristine muses "Well, it really doesn't matter. I've already accepted that my situation is a lost cause. ... But at least... I have Royal Sight!" Aristine sits on the ground, looking into a glowing swirl on the ground, as the narration explains: "The [Royal Sight] is the power to see the past, present and future through sleep. It's something that the Emperor coveted, but did not expect Aristine to possess. But she did inherit it."]

Note that the narration here says it's through sleep that Aristine has her visions, but in the story she's always portrayed as awake, looking into something.

(OP made a brief note about this, but doesn't appear to be coming back with a proper answer.)

Comment: I intended to ask a Meta question about whether or not I should self-answer if someone answered in the comments but never came back when I suggested writing an actual answer. Thanks for reminding me that I ought to do it.